# How to identify the membership sign up contact for an organisation

Tags: civimember

When a contact signs up for membership "on behalf of" an organisation, through a standard membership contribution page. The individual is then created with the employer/employee relationship to the organisation.

If the organisation has several employee contacts in the database is there a way of identifying the contact that recorded the membership? Is that stored somewhere in the bowels of the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was a paid membership then may be using Contribution activity you can track it down.

Answer (score 1):

For us it shows it as the 'added by contact' on the activities tab(s).

Comment: Agree. Activities for the Contribution, Membership status change and Membership sign up are all created on both records

Comment: Yeah, that rings true to me too. 

Sorry, I've dithered for a few days before accepting one answer.

Comment: Sorry again Rebecca for not choosing your answer!